# Solspace Calendar and Importer

Tags: mysql, solspace-calendar, solspace-importer

So I'm looking for a work around with Solspaces' Importer and Calendar module and hoping someone has a fix, hack or whatever for this.

My problem is that the two awesome modules *do not exactly work together*. Importer is great for taking a LOT of data and port that data into EE fields that you can run manually or on a cron. What it doesn't do however is port the DATES into Calendar DATES. This is a big problem for me since I'm using an API to pull in Events.

Has anyone discovered a way to do this? My thoughts were that I could possibly have the date (formatted like so: 2013-10-01 07:30 PM) into a *text field* and run a MySQL command that would port that information into my Solspace Calendar field.

Is this doable or even thinkable? :) Perhaps I should try [DataGrab](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/datagrab) instead? Or am I just stuck with having to edit each and every event to the end of time?

Answer (score 1):

We answered this privately, but we'll mentioning it here again for reference for other users, as it might be useful:

It's possible to import Calendar data through an .ics file (a calendaring file used in iCal, Google Calendar, etc, which contains calendar/event data). When creating a calendar entry in the "Calendar: Calendars" channel, there is a custom field for pasting a URL pointing to your .ics file. Saving the entry should import event data.

Comment: I've got the same issue, but could you post a link to an example ICS file which is formatted correctly for import to Calendar? Thanks

Comment: Here's an example: [https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/canadian__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics](https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/canadian__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics)